# Related Lists in Mini-Page Layout not working

Tags: visualforce

I could use some help from the assembled wisdom here.

I understand how what is visible in the "hover" boxes is edited. I have no problem adding fields from the associated records onto hover details. However I cannot get related lists information to show up in the hover boxes. I have selected the checkboxes I want displayed (in this case say it's Activities), along with the checkboxes inside "Activities," and "Activities" is still visible and on the page layout as a related list, and yet they don't show up in the hover boxes.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I literally walked through the SalesForce provided help file step-by-step and I can't figure out why they won't work.

Help!

Answer (score 3):

From [this](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=console_definelayouts.htm&siteLang=en_US) doc:

> Related lists on mini page layouts **only display in the Console tab**,
>   not hover details.